# file array output printing

Tags: php, file, input, types

i am using an array of file, i mean input type ="file" to upload number of files at a time.

i want to print or echo that file array values , how can i do this.

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array by suffixing `[]` to the name of the field:

```
<from method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myfile[]" />
 <input type="file" name="myfile[]" />
 <input type="file" name="myfile[]" />
 <!-- and so on -->
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 print_r($_FILES['myfile']);
}
```

Comment: how do i get the first array index file name

i mean the first array element name

or how to echo the first element of that array

eg: $_FILES['myfile']['name']

but how in the case of an array??
or how to echo the first element of that array

Comment: @tibin: You can do like `echo $_FILES['myfile'][0]`

Comment: @tibin mathew: I don't know what are you doing, please show the relevant html and php code.

Comment: This is the html code

<input type="file" name="frm_image[]" class="text_area">

Below is the php code

echo $_FILES['frm_image'][0];

Comment: @tibin: have you added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form` tag? see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
var_dump($_FILES['myfield']);
```